# How properly deploy Docker Compose to Amason EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm having docker-compose config with `postgres`, 2*`python`, `nginx` and `redis` services. Now I'm instantiated an ec2 instance and successfully logged in via `.pem` file. But I expected, that I can deploy my docker-compose image only with `aws-cli` commands. My question is should I instantiate ec2 for each of service and how to use ec2 with `docker-compose` properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you want to design your infrastructure - how many servers, autoscaling, routing, etc - is entirely up to you.

To answer your question though; to deploy a `docker-compose.yml` file you do so the same as you would on any other server.

`docker-compose` is a tool made for development and is not made to be used in Production - you should deploy your services with:

```
docker stack deploy -c your-compose-file.yml your_stack_name
```

It sounds like this is new to you though; so I should state that there are various options that are available with `docker-compose` that are not available with `docker stack deploy`. Often times you can't just use the same compose file as you're using in development.